# Understanding a Javascript Codewars challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
     var gimme = function (inputArray) {
     var order = inputArray.slice().sort(function(a,b) { return a-b;});
    return inputArray.indexOf(order[1]);
     };
```

This is a function to find the index number of the middle number in a sequence, when given a triplet of numbers. However I don't understand the section:

```
     (function(a,b) { return a-b;});
```

Could someone explain the purpose of this part? I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers);
```

The result is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`

So this is a very simple comparator for integers.

---

Comparators works like the following:

- if a < b, return a *negative*
- if b < a, return a *positive*
- in other cases, return *zero*

This function uses a simple mathematical property of integers.

Comment: Thanks so much! What do you mean when you say comparator?

Comment: A Comparator is an object which compares other objects and decides whether one is "larger" or they are equal. For example the `<=` operator, is a partial sort *comparator* on the set of real numbers.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.